# What triggers ConstraintException when loading DataSet?

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

How can I find out which column and value is violating the constraint? The exception message isn't helpful at all:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or
>   more rows contain values violating
>   non-null, unique, or foreign-key
>   constraints.

Comment: I'd give you more up-votes if I could.  This is a thorn in my side as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a property called RowError you can check.

See http://dotnetdebug.net/2006/07/16/constraintexception-a-helpful-tip/

Edited to add this link showing iteration of rows to see which had errors.

http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet/topic58812.aspx

Answer (score 23):

Like many people, I have my own standard data access components, which include methods to return a DataSet.  Of course, if a ConstraintException is thrown, the DataSet isn't returned to the caller, so the caller can't check for row errors.

What I've done is catch and rethrow ConstraintException in such methods, logging row error details, as in the following example (which uses Log4Net for logging):

```
...
try
{
    adapter.Fill(dataTable); // or dataSet
}
catch (ConstraintException)
{
    LogErrors(dataTable);
    throw;
}
...

private static void LogErrors(DataSet dataSet)
{
    foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        LogErrors(dataTable);
    }
}

private static void LogErrors(DataTable dataTable)
{
    if (!dataTable.HasErrors) return;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat(
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        "ConstraintException while  filling {0}",
        dataTable.TableName);
    DataRow[] errorRows = dataTable.GetErrors();
    for (int i = 0; (i < MAX_ERRORS_TO_LOG) && (i < errorRows.Length); i++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.Append(errorRows[i].RowError);
    }
    _logger.Error(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Your LogErrors method is great!  Literally saved me today.

Answer (score 3):

When you use a strong typed dataset and used the visual designer (xsd): to access *tbl.Rows[0].RowError* information, you need to create the **Fill** method.

You **can't use the Get** method, since the DataTable is instanced within generated code.

Comment: like you said, you need a fill. Very strange; why would I need a fill statement when i'm only getting some data (basic select). Somewhere inside thought this Fill method is used by .net it seems. After i generated a Fill method (no change on the get) it worked.

Answer (score 3):

For googlers who want a snippet to get more details on the ConstraintException:

```
try
{
    ds.EnforceConstraints = true;
}
catch (ConstraintException ex)
{
    string details = string.Join("",
        ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>()
            .Where(t => t.HasErrors)
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetErrors())
            .Take(50)
            .Select(r => "\n - " + r.Table.TableName + "[" + string.Join(", ", r.Table.PrimaryKey.Select(c => r[c])) + "]: " + r.RowError));
    throw new ConstraintException(ex.Message + details);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added some code that I've found to be useful in debugging ConstraintException occurrences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936/handling-xsd-dataset-constraintexceptions#37951)

Hope this helps.