# C# DataSet GetChanges() throw exception

Tags: c#

I have a DataSet where the GetChanges() return this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.ConstraintException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>       Additional information: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

How can I tell in what table the problem is?

It happens before I save the tables. If I skip the Getchanges(), the save is OK.

Thanks

Comment: The information supplied is telling you exactly why. See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d40xefa.aspx) for further information. How many tables are referenced in the Dataset?

Comment: The DataSet holds many table, in the currnet ViewModel (I'm using MVVM) I load only few. I've checked them all whith GetErros(), all where OK.

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/140679/206367) and log the error. This should clue you in more.